# Как убирать класс у другого экземпляра компонента по клику?

Tags: reactjs

Есть вот такой компонент:

```
 export const ButtonRoom = (props) => {
        const [activeRoom, setActiveRoom] = useState(false)
        const setRoom = () => {
            setActiveRoom(!activeRoom)
        }
        return(
            <button onClick={()=>setRoom()} className={activeRoom ? "room__active button" : "button"}>
            </button>
        )
    }
```

На данный момент я могу присвоить/убрать класс по клику только у элемента на котором производится клик, а как убрать класс у другого экземпляра компонента?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-khayyam-pj138?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark
Блин тут ссылка не считается за 30 символов.